# Excel formula: Add Column A value if Column B value is between X and Y

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I've been looking all over for an answer to this, but I've had a hard time finding one.

My data looks like this, but much longer:

```
Sessions (A)   Screen Width (B)
875            1020
869            1580
864            1520
809            1420
```

I'm looking for a formula that will come up with a sum of all values in column A, but only if the value in column B is between 768 and 1024 (as one example).

I am but a lowly designer, and do not understand things like numbers and formulas. :)

Seriously though, I tried SUMIF and SUMIFS and a few other things, but couldn't figure out if I was on the right path or not.

I really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: `=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,">=768",B:B,"<=1024")`???

Comment: What formulas did you try? If you show us what you tried, we can show you where your logic may have "gone wrong", and help explain why.

Comment: See [HERE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) for more on how to use SUMIFS.  There is even a good video.

Comment: @ScottCraner Gosh darn it all!

Comment: Sorry I didn't post my formulas, but I tried a whole bunch of them and couldn't remember them all.

Scott's formula worked perfectly! One problem I discovered was that my Column A values were stored as text, so I had to include a Value() in the mix.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @ForwardEd - What'd you ask? What doesn't work in `SumIfs()`?

Comment: @BruceWayne He tried to use the MEDIAN(B:B,768,1024) as the criteria.

Comment: @BruceWayne {=SUMIF(A:A,B:B,MEDIAN(B:B,768,1024)} and the original version was not even with the CSE

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Scott Craner:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,">=768",B:B,"<=1024")
```

I had a secondary problem, which was that my Column A values were stored as text rather than numbers, which why everything I tried kept coming up 0. To fix that, I had to include Value() in my formula.